About Mapping an actual number of polygon from Image to Shapefile
Is there any plugin or Third-party tool or logic that can be implement in a python for the stated task :
I have one Image with a few numbers of polygon and each polygon have a number. but when a GIS software creates map file (Shapefile) of that image, it is not containing a number of that polygon.
In an attribute table of a shapefile, the existence of each number of a polygon should assign to it's corresponding polygon in shapefile. so how does that possible.?
If somebody reads and if you have a single little bit stuff then please share with me. this can be help me a lot.
I have tried it using python and some functionalities like, open attribute table, insertion of the data from JSON file, co-ordinates of a polygon in shapefile etc,  working properly.
but I want to extract the number of that polygon which is mentioned in a polygon and insert to the attribute table of shapefile(of that image file).
